# C# Datagridview does not sort Checkbox column

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, checkbox

When I bind a Linq-to-sql query to a datagridview (using a BindingSource in between), the columns are sortable by default. However, this does not seem to be the case for boolean types. For these the datagridview uses Checkbox columns, but when I click on the header nothing happens. Solution anyone?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In VS2012 in the designer you can also set the SortMode.

Right-click on the DataGridView and go to "Edit Columns".

There's a drop-down for SortMode with a choice of NotSortable, Automatic, and Programmatic.

It appears that the default for most columns is Automatic, but for checkboxes (boolean) columns the default is NotSortable.

Answer (score 10):

will this help?

```
dgv1.Columns["Colname"].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
```