# datagridview checkboxcolumn sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have this datagridview where i have several checkboxcolumns. The datasource for the datagridview is a datatable. I wish to be able to sort the checkboxcolumn if I click the columnheader, but is it possible? And how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.  Click on the link on the link below for the answer.  Somebody asked that question before:

[C# Datagridview does not sort Checkbox column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979848/c-sharp-datagridview-does-not-sort-checkbox-column)

Comment: Yes i have seen that question, but the awnser requires that the datagridview is build by "me" and not just have af datatable as a datasource right? At the moment when I run the program i dont know how many checkboxcolumns there will be in the datagridview, when the data is loaded.